# JSON to Array binding in select Typescript

Tags: arrays, json, angular, typescript

JSON

```
{
    "bloodGroup":[
      {"Id":1, "Value":"O +ve", "Description":"OPositive"}, 
      {"Id":2, "Value":"O -ve", "Description":"ONegative"}, 
      {"Id":3, "Value":"AB +ve", "Description":"ABPositive"}
    ],
    "Gender":[
      {"Id":1, "Value":"Male", "Description":"Male"}, 
      {"Id":2, "Value":"Female", "Description":"Female"}
    ]
}
```

Pipe:

```
  transform(aList: Lookup[], lookUpName: string): Lookup[] {
    if (!aList || !lookUpName || aList.length === 0) {
        return aList;
    }

  return Array.of(aList[lookUpName])
}
```

Lookup Class (autogenerated from nswag):

```
export interface ILookup {
    name?: string | undefined;
    value?: string | undefined;
    description?: string | undefined;
}
```

HTML:

```
  <option *ngFor="let gender of aList | lookupFilter:'Gender'" [value]="gender.Id">
              {{gender.Value}}
  </option>
```

The select doesn't bind the required values. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: i think the issue is with Pipe. can you update question with complete pipe class

Comment: is it needed to use `lookupFilter`. cannot it used as `<option *ngFor="let gender of aList.Gender" [value]="gender.Id">{{gender.Value}}</option>`

Comment: Seems a good option, didn't think of it as it was a different scenaio before so i was using the filterPipe. Will give it a try @SudarshanaDayananda

Comment: Worked just like that, thank you @SudarshanaDayananda Still i'm curious why didn't this work. Anyways will use the method u proposed.

Comment: check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Array.of(aList[lookUpName])` to `aList[lookUpName]`. Everything will work fine.

```
 transform(aList: Lookup[], lookUpName: string): Lookup[] {

    if (!aList || !lookUpName || aList.length === 0) {
        return aList;
    }
    return aList[lookUpName];
}
```

**[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-57121709?file=src/app/app.component.ts).**

Comment: I was trying to convert JSON to array to bind the values to select, so select works directly with json which i don't know. Thanks again. Will mark your name for my future work, please help out.